# Vue3 element not displaying

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm new to vue and i'm starting a project where i want to use a library https://github.com/tochoromero/vuejs-smart-table.

At the moment i have a simple app:

```
<template>
    <img alt="Vue logo" class="logo" src="./assets/logo.svg" width="125" height="125" />

    <v-table :data="users">
      <thead slot="head">
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Age</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody slot="body" slot-scope="{displayData}">
          <tr v-for="row in displayData" :key="row.id">
            <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.title }}</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </v-table>
  </template>

<script>
import users from './data/karaoke.json'

export default {
    name: 'users',
    data: () => ({
        users
    })
}
</script>
```

That should read the rows from my karaoke.json and display them as a table right? At least following the documentation here https://tochoromero.github.io/vuejs-smart-table/the-basics/#table.

What happens is that nothing is displayed on the page, is just the vue logo and the DOM for the vtable is empty. On the other side if i use vue chrome dev tools and inspect the page i can see that the vtable actually does have data in it, is just not being displayed.
[image]

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? The code is live in this repo https://github.com/jiwidi/lens_database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your markup is for the Vue 2 version of Smart Table. Check out [the docs](https://vue-smart-table.netlify.app/getting-started.html) for the new Vue 3 compatible version (which is the package you're using).  You need to use a `<template>` tag now to pass in slot props.

```
<v-table :data="users">
 <template #head>
   <thead slot="head">
     <th>Title</th>
     <th>Artist</th>
   </thead>
 </template>
 <template #body="{ rows }">
   <tbody>
     <tr v-for="row in rows" :key="row.id">
       <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
       <td>{{ row.title }}</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </template>
</v-table>
```